Stream/retrieve all native SOL transfers above a certain value
I'm trying to stream (or alternatively, repeatedly historically obtain over a short period of time) all native SOL transfers from a single sender wallet to a single receiver wallet. That is to say, I wish to omit all transfers that involve more than two wallets, and any transfers that involve tokens that are not native Solana (SOL) (this means ignoring WSOL too).
What's the best way to do this? I'm using Python, and the python solana.rpc package helps me stream all SOL transfers, or obtain the last 1000 transfers, however the get_transaction(Signature) function takes around a second per transaction. With approximately 1 transaction every 0.04 seconds, we lag excessively.
